# Making React useEffect check whether video link has video available

Tags: reactjs, video, react-hooks

I'm facing one difficulty. I'm working on custom video player and I'm trying to check with useEffect whether video source has video (it opens a link, but never starts). Here is a link with the video http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm

What I want to do is to check for 5 seconds whether video can be loaded and if not - change the isLoaded state to false, block controls and if in 5 seconds it's not solved - redirect to error route (or console.log for instance). If everything is fine and everything loads - change isLoaded to true and start video right after it's available.

I can check whether videoRef's current.duration is not equal to 0 or current.networkState, but I don't know how to check it for 5 seconds and start if everything is allright.

Here is my code:

```
const PlayerScreen = (props) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    video.oncanplay = () => {
      setIsPlaying(true);
      video.play();
    };

    video.onplay = () => {
      setIsPlaying(true);
    };

    video.onpause = () => {
      setIsPlaying(false);
    };

    video.ontimeupdate = () => {
      if (video.currentTime !== 0) {
        handleTimeElapsed();
        handleProgress();
      }
    };

    return () => {
      video.oncanplaythrough = null;
      video.onplay = null;
      video.onpause = null;
      video.ontimeupdate = null;
    };
  }, []);

  const {
    film: {
      previewImg,
      videoSrc
    },
  } = props;

  return (
    <div className="player">
      <video
        className="player__video"
        ref={videoRef}
        src={videoSrc} // http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm 
        poster={previewImg}
      />
    </div>)
}
```

Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: Could you send me a video which is working ? I have to do some test before answering you a potenial fix

Comment: Sure! Thanks! Here it is: http://peach.themazzone.com/durian/movies/sintel-1024-surround.mp4

Comment: I posted an answer, le me know if it working. Normally it is because I tested in a codesandbox :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some tests to see how you can handle your state if a video is unavaible

in your useEffect make a requests to sees if there is a network error or not and set a timeout to avoid the fetch time to be infinite.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const result = await Axios.get(
          "http://media.xiph.org/mango/tears_of_steel_1080p.webm",
          { timeout: 5000}
        );
        // Do something here
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("The link is not avaible", e.message);
        // Do something here
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

If there is no error in your fetch, The useEffect will not catch an error and you can write your code

Comment: damn, in my project I'm not allowed to use anything newer than ES6. that's why async/await is not solving my problem. but I'm pretty sure it should work!

Comment: It's weird, normally react support ES6

Comment: I mean async/await is I guess ES8 and I need to stay in ES6

Comment: You can use fetch and catch